# Execute Shell Commands from Excel Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, shell, vba

I have a shell command, to execute a program with additional arguments.

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVnc\vncviewer" & " " & Range("$G3")
```

The cell G3 contains an IP address I wish to start the program with.

I have no issues starting the command from a command button, but what i wish to do is to start the program with arguments from a hyperlinked cell, using:

```
= HYPERLINK("C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVnc\vncviewer" & " " & Range("$G3"))
```

But the hyperlink can't open the program with optional arguments.

Is there someway I can open the program from hyperlink with the optional arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out using VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("range here")) Is Nothing Then
   Call Shell("program location" & " " & Target)
Else
```

Now I double click on a cell in the sheet containing the IP, and that will run my program with that IP.

Answer (score 0):

Excel hyperlinks are good for opening web pages, PDF files, or other files that are compatible with Microsoft Office. But there are certain issues when using a hyperlink to open a command file like EXE, BAT, CMD, VBS, etc. For example:

• A warning dialog box with OK/Cancel buttons must be negotiated.

• It is not convenient to add command line arguments, especially if they depend upon other cells.

• The command file’s path might be difficult to specify, especially if the Excel file is moved.

• When a command file’s shortcut is specified, its type (.LNK) must be included.

• A shell window will flash when long or complex script files like CMD or VBS are opened.

The technique described here addresses these issues without impacting standard Excel hyperlinks: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2017/09/14/excel-hyperlinks-run-command-files/

This solution adds text that looks like RUN::COMMAND to the hyperlink’s cell, then process that text using VBA added to the worksheet’s FollowHyperlink event code. For example, if the hyperlink’s cell displays

```
This cell is a hyperlink to RUN::"Notepad.exe" "SomeFilePath.BAS"
```

then the specified BAS file will be opened in Notepad.